# How add 'swipe/touch' to a 'jquery circular carousel'

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, carousel

I'm using [jquery circular carousel](https://github.com/sgb-io/jquery.circular-carousel)
for a 3D carousel with its Next and Previous button to rotate it.(which all works fine)

I now want to add mobile devices's '**swipe**' capability to also rotate the carousel .
The structure for the carousel is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/3D_rotating_carousel/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css//3D_rotating_carousel/jquery.circular-carousel.css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/jquery.circular-carousel.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>

<div class="container" style="height:500px;">
  <ol class="carousel">
    <li class="item active">
        <img src="images/guitar10.jpg" alt="" /></li>
    ...
    <li class="item">
        <img src="images/guitar19.jpg" alt="" /></li>
  </ol>
</div>

<div class="controls">
 <a tabindex="4" href="#" class="previous hyperlink" >Previous</a> 
 <a tabindex="5" href="#" class="next hyperlink" >Next</a>
</div>
```

I've now added:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js"/> <!-- needed for 'touch' on mobiles -->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {  
        $(".container").swiperight(function() {  
            $(this).carousel('previous');  
        });  
     $(".container").swipeleft(function() {  
      $(this).carousel('next');  
       });  
    });  
</script>
```

But I obviously haven't understood the above references correctlly as the 'swipe' doesn't work.  I'm also having to borrow an iPad for testing - and the time I can borrow it is limited  - the owner seems lost without it ;-)

Can someone help me understand what's wromg - thanks.

Comment: try touch js events -- http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/touchevents.shtml

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation/demo of the carousel, you're using its API wrong. `$(this).carousel('previous')` won't do anything. The plugin adds just a `CircularCarousel` method to jQuery to initialize the carousel. It then (somewhat unusually for jQuery) returns an object whose methods you can use. You need to save this object, and then reference it in your swipe callback. The method is called `cycleActive`.

```
var carousel = $('.selector').CircularCarousel(options);
$(".selector").swiperight(function() {  
    carousel.cycleActive('previous');  
});
```

Comment: No wonder I couln't solve it, thanks VERY much for your help, but I'm still in a quandry about where to put it this code and which selectors are which.

Is this right?

var carousel = $('.selector-where-the swipe-can-be').CircularCarousel(options);
$(".selector-in-my-case=.carousel").swiperight(function() {  
    carousel.cycleActive('previous');  
}); 

Do I need to repeat these line for 'next'?
$(".selector-in-my-case=.carousel").swiperight(function() {  
    carousel.cycleActive('next');  
});      and what goes in your "options"?

Tks again for your help

Comment: That looks about right. You need to repeat the lines for next, and the options are the carousel options (you can check those out on the plugin github page).